# Club Election Voting Permutation Question

Tags: permutations, combinations

In a club election the number of contestants is one more than the number of maximum candidates for which a voter can vote. If the total number of ways is which a voter can vote be 62, then the number of candidates is:

My Approach!
Let's suppose we have m voters and n be the maximum candidate so total number of contestants becomes n+1. 
Now each voter can vote in n+1 ways. So m voters can vote in m* (n+1) ways which is equal to 62.

That's it, I am not able to figure it out more.

Comment: That doesn't seem right ... it says that the number of ways a voter can vote is 62 ... so it seems like we are talking about 1 voter here, not all $m$ voters

Comment: 1) you dont need "number of voters", because the question asks "the number of ways in which ONE voter can vote is 62"

Comment: 2) hint for the actual question: Its a kinda weird kind of election you are asked about. In this election one single voter can cast anywhere between $1$ and $n-1$ votes (for different candidates of course. one voter can not vote for the same candidate twice).

Comment: Sorry guys, You are correct. Thanks for helping out. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the only restrictions on who you can vote for are that you can't vote for everybody, and you can't vote for nobody. So you can vote for any subset of the $n$ candidates except those two. So you have $2^n-2$ different ways to vote, and so $2^n=64$.

Answer (score 0):

Let there be $n$ candidates (contestants), and I assume that you have to vote for at least one of them, then 
the number of ways of casting votes is $\binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2} + \dotsc + \binom{n}{n-1}$.
[ Remember, you can only vote for a maximum of n-1 ]

Now it is known that the sum of the binomial coefficients, 
$$\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \dotsc + \binom{n}{n} = 2^n$$
subtracting $\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{n} = 1 + 1$, 
the number of ways to vote is $2^n - 2 = 62$
\begin{gather}
2^n = 64 \\
2^n = 2^6 \\
n = 6
\end{gather}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).